# Triggers on multiple tables and update it into single column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a requirement where, on updating employee form. I have to keep track which fields updated by user. The employee form we are saving has total of 6 tables.
When user updates any column, I want to track the old value and the new value that he changed.

For that I have created a Audit logs table, In that I have kept fields like, id, employee_id, table_name, old_value, new_value

So suppose when user edits two columns in employee form, i.e firstname and lastname. I want to save those two records in old value column in two different rows individually. i.e in first record, it should get the firstname and in second record it should get lastname.
& any column that i change related to any of the 6 tables then it should update in my trigger table
Please suggest me how to get this query

Below I have written a basic trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER advance_audit 
BEFORE UPDATE ON employee 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO employees_audit 
    SET action = 'update', old_name= OLD.firstname, old_name = OLD.lastname;
```

Comment: If you need 2 separate rows then you need in 2 separate INSERT queries.

Comment: If using mariadb, [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) support this preservation natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER advance_audit 
AFTER UPDATE ON employee 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.firstname <> OLD.firstname THEN 
    INSERT INTO employees_audit (action, column_name, old_name, new_name, operator)
    VALUES ('update', 'firstname', OLD.firstname, NEW.firstname, SYSTEM_USER());
END IF;
IF NEW.lastname <> OLD.lastname THEN 
    INSERT INTO employees_audit (action, column_name, old_name, new_name, operator)
    VALUES ('update', 'lastname', OLD.lastname, NEW.lastname, SYSTEM_USER());
END IF;
-- the same blocks for each another column to be audited
END
```

Use AFTER trigger. It will not save into the log if the query fails.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Akina, I will now implement with the query which you have provided

Comment: Akina, The above query you provided working fine, But I have nearly 50 columns in my table, I have to write 50 conditions, Please suggest me how to write the above query using while loop

Comment: @Sonu If you want to WRITE the trigger code using loop than you may (for example, in Excel). But do not try to loop over the columns list in the trigger - you need in dynamic SQL which is not allowed in triggers.

Comment: Ok Akina, Can you please give me any suggestion, what to do next. or any way to do without hardcoding all the columns

Comment: @Sonu There is no the possibility to perform this dynamically, without columns names hardcoding. Or at least I have never seen/listen about such possibility. And ideologically - the table structure must be deterministic, and its altering must be accompanied with according triggers editions.